# Knockout.js using open ended tags in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have the following code...

```
<div data-bind="foreach:profiles">
    <!-- ko if: $index() % 3 === 3 -->
            <div class="form-group">
    <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 no-padding-left">
                  <img class="img-circle text-center" src="\Content\images\fake_profile_pics\md.png" alt=".." style="opacity: 1.9" />
                  <h5 class="text-center"><span data-bind="text:Points"></span><span> points</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-3">
                  <a href="#" class="profile_popover people-h2" data-bind="text:DisplayName"></a>
                  <span class="display-block" data-bind="text:Division"></span>
                  <span class="display-block"><span data-bind="text:NominationsWritten"></span><span> Nominations Written</span></span>
            </div>
     <!-- ko if: $index() % 3 === 1 -->
            </div>
     <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

I am trying to create a row of objects, 3 objects wide, that all start at the height of the lowest element of the row above it. The problem with this code is that knockout cannot find an end tag to the first div, and breaks without errors. If you place an end tag within the first 'ko if' statement everything works fine.

Is this possible to do using the knockout commenting method, or is there a more accepted way of tackling this problem with knockout?

Comment: Why not rewrite your if statement? Order your elements in code and then just run through the foreach

Comment: BTW: `if: $index() % 3 === 3` this statement is *never* true. Presumably you mean `if: $index() % 3 === 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show your view model, but for this kind of problem, I think it is much easier to use a `computed` property in your view model and bind to that rather than mix a lot of view model logic into your view. For example, if you have this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.someStuff = ko.observableArray();
    //... other props
}
```

I'd just add a computed property like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var numCols = 3;
    self.someStuff = ko.observableArray();

    self.columns = ko.computed(function () {
        var source = self.someStuff();
        if (source && source.length) {
            var cols = [];
            for (var i=0; i < source.length; i+=numCols) {
                cols.push(source.slice(i,numCols));
            }
            return cols;
        }
    });
    //... other props
}
```

Note: you might be able to come up with better ways to partition the array.

Then you can just bind it like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:columns">
    <div class="form-group" data-bind="foreach:$data>
        <div>
            <!-- bind whatever properties you want here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you keep that ugly logic out of your view. And you computed property will be reevaluated any time your observable array changes.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Matt, I was hoping there was something more straightforward but this works. If anyone knows a better way to do this post it.

Comment: @BrandonMcAlees: I'd say that is pretty straight forward, much better at least than including a lot of logic in your view model. `computed` properties are well worth understanding and using for this type of thing. If it's too complicated for a `computed` property, then you can also look at custom bindings, which aren't that difficult to use either.

Comment: Geate solution! I though think for the "cols.push(source.slice(i,numCols));" you should actually put "cols.push(source.slice(i, i + numCols));", as the slice function works based on the startIndex/endIndex parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than the inline `if` why not always render the wrapping `div` with the conditional `class`?

```
<div data-bind="css: { 'form-group': $index() % 3 === 3 }">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Hunter, thanks for the response. I don't think that will work because the end tag has to be rendered after the foreach has ran 3 times, or if it is the last element in the foreach.

Comment: ahh, I see. Another alternative would be to have 2 loops if you're able to group the data beforehand